# Quote of Umar being corrected by a female in friday sermon

Tags: history, reference-request

I came across that Umar (RA) was once corrected by a woman in his friday sermon and he admitted she was right. Can someone please show me what was the conversation exactly or a gist of it?

This is the reference cited in an [article](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/4713562/Website-Paper-PDFs/FINAL_-An-Open-Letter-to-Muslim-Men_-The-Sunnah-Trumps-Toxic-Masculinity.pdf?__hstc=251652889.a840a9051e7cbf17058057ca21595064.1563561480354.1563563555950.1564022951785.3&__hssc=251652889.11.1564022951785) I was reading but I am unable to find the conversation.

> Abū Jaʿfar al-Ṭaḥāwī, Sharḥ mushkil al-āthār, ed. Shuʿayb al-Arnā’ūṭ
>   (Beirut: Mu’assasat al-Risāla, 1987), 13:57. Ibn Kathīr affirms the
>   report; Ibn Kathīr, Tafsīr, ed. Muṣṭafā al-Sayyid Muḥammad, et al.
>   (Giza: Mu’assasat Qurṭuba, 2000), 3:403.

Comment: Are you looking for a reference only or do you want to check the authenticity

Comment: @Medi1Saif The content in the reference only. Umh has provided the answer I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference cites:

- (شرح مشكل الآثار (ت: الأرناؤوط -
  [Vol 13, page 57](https://archive.org/stream/WAQ1027/sma13#page/n55/mode/2up) ([pdf](https://ia800704.us.archive.org/0/items/WAQ1027/sma13.pdf))
- (تفسير ابن كثير (ط. مؤسسة قرطبة - [Vol 3, page 403](https://archive.org/stream/FPtkather/tkather03#page/n402/mode/2up) ([pdf](https://ia800900.us.archive.org/9/items/FPtkather/tkather03.pdf))

The translation provided in the [abridged edition of Tafsir Ibn Kathir](https://archive.org/details/tafsir_ibn_kathir/page/n1103) published by Darussalam, is as follows:

> Umar bin Al-Khattab stood up on the Minbar of the Messenger of Allah ﷺ
>   and said, 'O people! Why do you exaggerate concerning the dowry given
>   to women? The Messenger of Allah ﷺ and his Companions used to pay up
>   to four hundred Dirhams for a dowry, or less than that. Had paying
>   more for a dowry been a part of Taqwa or an honor, you would not have
>   led them in this practice. Therefore, I do not want to hear about a
>   man who pays more than four hundred Dirhams for a dowry.'
>
> He then went down the Minbar, but a woman from Quraysh said to him, 'O
>   Leader of the Faithful! You prohibited people from paying more than
>   four hundred Dirhams in a dowry for women?'
>
> He said, 'Yes.'
>
> She said, 'Have you not heard what Allah sent down in the Qur'an?'
>
> He said, 'Which part of it?'
>
> She said, 'Have you not heard Allah's statement:
>
> > وآتيتم إحداهن قنطارا
> >
> > And you have given one of them a Qintar
> >
> > <sup>— [Quran 4:20](http://quran.com/4/20)</sup>
>
> He said, 'O Allah! Forgive me...'
>
> He then went back and stood up on the Minbar saying, 'I had prohibited
>   you from paying more than four hundred Dirhams in a dowry for women.
>   So, let everyone pay what he likes from his money.'

Comment: For the grading of authenticity of this report see: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/79464/